# Pass data using swiftyJSON from viewcontroller to class

Tags: swift, swift3, swifty-json, ios10

i'm a newbie and still learning about swift 3, and i have a trouble in here. I'm using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON for geting JSON data from Open Weather API. I create an apps using tableview for showing forecast data from API.
From what i learn, i should place the JSON code in Model (class) and viewcontroller only for call that. But i've got a problem cause this JSON is array with key like this:

```
"list":[  
    {  
        "dt":1473134400,
        "temp":{  
            "day":298.71,
            "min":298.15,
            "max":298.71,
            "night":298.15,
            "eve":298.71,
            "morn":298.71
```

*list is looping.

i want to get the min and max data from that JSON. but not sure how to parse data from this viewcontroller to init in class with swiftyJSON. cause i learn this from some of video, but they are using dictionary..

this is my view controller

```
func downloadForecastWeatherDetail(completed: DownloadComplete){
    let forecastWeatherUrl = URL(string: FORECAST_WEATHER_URL)
    Alamofire.request(forecastWeatherUrl!, withMethod: .get).responseJSON {response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value)
                if let list = json["list"].array {
                    //print(list)
                    for (key,subJSON) in json["list"]{
                        let forecasting = Forecast(weatherDict: subJSON)
                        self.forecast.append(forecasting)
                        print(forecasting)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

here is my class:

```
init(weatherDict: JSON){
    if let min = weatherDict["temp"]["min"].double{
        self._forecastLowTemp = min
        print("\(self._forecastLowTemp)min")
    }
    if let max = weatherDict["temp"]["max"].double{
        self._forecastHighTemp = max
        print("\(self._forecastHighTemp)max")
    }
}
```

this code is not works.. so once again my question is, how to pass data from list in vc to init in class with using SwiftyJSON? cause i need to append it to "forecast" array class to show it in tableview. Sorry for my long question

Comment: Try to loop list data this way  `for listItemAsJSON in json["list"].arrayValue{` and pass the `listItemAsJSON` to your `init` method. Also use `.doubleValue` instead of `.double` for retrieving the data.

Comment: in my class for my init, is it correct if i used init(weatherDict: JSON ) ? @Ayazmon

Comment: It works, thanks for your help @Ayazmon!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)